How to use nonlinear animation with Dynamic Parent?
I made a weapon animation. In my Idle animation the only thing that moves is an arm, but a gun is connected to the arm through dynamic parent. So when I use nonlinear animation and try add next action gun does nothing in Idle animation. So basically arm moves and a gun doesn't. What I want is that when I chose an action Idle I want a arm and a gun move upside down. And on then go to the next action. But when I add next action gun isn't moving at all

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am using nonlinear animation editor to combine several actions in .blend file. One action is idle and a second one is reload. In the Idle I have two rigs. One is an arm rig and second one is an weapon rig. Using a Dynamic Parent addon made that gun is following movement of the hand. And animated a hand movement afterwards. When I started to sort actions in nonlinear animation editor it turn out that Idle animation doesn't affect gun rig at all even though I used dynamic parent so it could make gun rig follow the arm rig.  I want is to know why its not following it anymore and how to fix this

Could you add some screenshots of your NLA editor and your rigs?

I can add only one image for some reason, but here it is
